# How to align by vertical label and textarea in one div?

Tags: html, css

There is the following HTML code:

```
<div class="row">
<label class="resume-form-label" for="ResumeForm_languages">Languages</label><textarea class="resume-form-input" name="ResumeForm[languages]" id="ResumeForm_languages"></textarea></div>
```

And the following styles:

```
.row
{
    margin: 5px 0;
}

.resume-form-label {
    display: inline-block;
    width:100px;
    background: yellow;
}

.resume-form-input {
    width:300px;
}

.row {
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

I need to have label and div aligned by vertical. How can I do it? Now it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

like this: http://jsfiddle.net/matias/BGwBp/

CSS:

```
.row
{
    margin: 5px 0;
}

.resume-form-label {
    display: inline-block;
    width:100px;
    background: yellow;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.resume-form-input {
    width:300px;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much! I tried it, but I had the following problem: I thought it was enough to add "vertical-align" to .resume-form-label, but it didn't work. Now I've just added "vertical-align" to both label and input and it works! Why?

Comment: That's the way it works. You have to assign the vertical align property to both inline-block elements.

Comment: Also, why can't I do ".row label, input {
    vertical-align: middle;
}" ?

Comment: if you want to do it like that, you should do it like this: ".row label, .row input { vertical-align: middle; }"